# A short question for the command \LaTeX

Tags: spacing

Why the command `\LaTeX` (and I think also `\TeX`, `\XeLaTeX`, etc.) is missing of a blank space?

I add my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Far far away, behind the word mountains \LaTeX far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: *every* command suppress following spaces. Use `\LaTeX{} far`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It was a question I always had in my mind. So that's just because I don't have a space. Thank you immensely. If there are no answers, you can safely close my question.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yessssssssss :-).